# Prove that $p_M+p_{M^\perp}=I$, where $I$ is the identity on $H$.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

$M$ is a subspace of $H$, a vector spaces of finite dimension with an inner product $\langle \rangle$; $p_M$ is the orthogonal projection on $M$ and $M^\perp$ is the orthogonal complement of $M$.

Prove that $p_M+p_{M^\perp}=I$, where $I$ is the identity on $H$.

I am unsure how to prove this statement. The premise of the problem seems obviously true so it is giving me difficulties in beginning the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w_1,\ldots,w_k$ be an orthonormal basis of $M$. Then, $p_Mv=\sum_i\left<v,w_i\right>w_i$.

Then for any $\forall j\in\{1,\ldots, k\}$, we have
$$
\left<v-p_Mv,w_j\right>=\left<v,w_j\right>+\sum_i\left<v,w_i\right>\left<w_i,w_j\right>\\
=\left<v,w_j\right>-\left<v,w_j\right>\left<w_j,w_j\right>=\left<v,w_j\right>-\left<v,w_j\right>=0.
$$
This proves $v-p_Mv\in M^\perp$, from which the conclusion follows:
$$
v-p_Mv=p_{M^\perp}(v-p_Mv)=p_{M^\perp}v-p_{M^\perp}p_Mv=p_{M^\perp}v-0=p_{M^\perp}v.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $H\simeq M\oplus M^{\perp}$, any vector $v\in H$ can be uniquely written as a sum $v=m+m'$ with $m\in M,m'\in M^{\perp}$. Then apply $p:=p_M+p_{M^{\perp}}$. By definition of projection, $p_M(m)=m$ and $p_M(m')=0$, and similarly $p_{M^{\perp}}(m)=0$ and $p_{M^{\perp}}(m')=m'$. Taking the sum gives you $p(v)=p_M(m+m')+p_{M^{\perp}}(m+m')=m+m'=v$ for any $v$, so $p=I$.

Comment: What is $\oplus$?

Comment: It is direct sum of vector spaces. Do you know what that is?